# ¿En que consiste que el setTimeout efectúe la pausa en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, web

Estoy haciendo un programa que haga un ordenamiento y lo muestre en el canvas con lineas. El problema es que lo ejecuta de golpe aunque ya le hay puesto un setTimeout("FuncionDeDibujo()",1000). Simplemente no hace la pausa de 1seg. 
Ya intenté quitarle las comillas y ponerlo de manera distinta y nada y si lo dibuja pero de golpe. Quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal. Adjunto codigo:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var arreglo = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++ )
        arreglo[i] = Math.round(10+Math.random()*100); 

    console.log(arreglo);
    ordenamientoBurbuja(arreglo);
}
function showSort(arreglo){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        if(canvas && canvas.getContext){
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                if(ctx){
                    //LINEA
                    ctx.lineWidth = 20;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";

                    var x = 0;
                    for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length;i++){
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(x,300);
                        ctx.lineTo(x,0+arreglo[i]);
                        ctx.stroke();
                        x+=21;
                    }
                }
        }
}

function ordenamientoBurbuja(arreglo){
    for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length-1;i++){
        for( var j = i + 1;j < arreglo.length;j++){
            if(arreglo[i] < arreglo[j]){
                var aux = arreglo[i];
                    arreglo[i] = arreglo[j];
                    arreglo[j] = aux;
                    //showSort(arreglo);
                    window.setTimeout(showSort(arreglo),1000);

                }
            }
        }
        //console.log(arreglo);
}
```

Intenté ponerlo también dentro del window.onload inicial y nada.
PD: Usé el método de la burbuja inicialmente porque es el mas sencillo y solo quiero que funcione en general para posteriormente ponerle los mas complejos.

Comment: Si esta bien 1000, 1000 milisegundos =  1 segundo

Answer (score 1):

`SetTimeout` recibe la definicion de la función, si la escribes con los paréntesis, se ejecuta en el momento. Para pasar un parámetro tienes que usar el tercer parámetro.

```js
function showSort(arreglo) {
  console.log(arreglo)
}

setTimeout(showSort, 1000, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Si la función retornaría otra función, si podrías hacer eso:

```js
function showSort() {
  return arreglo => {
    console.log(arreglo)
  }
}

setTimeout(showSort(), 1000, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Si quieres que cada un segundo se ejecute algo con `setTimeout` dentro de un for tienes que incrementar el tiempo cada vez, 1000 por cada iteración:

```js
function showSort(parametro) {
  console.log(parametro);
}

for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

  setTimeout(showSort, 1000 * (j + 1), [1, 2, 3]);

}
```

Si no lo incrementas, el setTimeout empieza a esperar ni bien se define la función, que es casi al mismo tiempo, entonces hace todo junto.

Comment: Efectivamente, pero eso soluciono en parte el problema. Ahora lo unico que hace es que se pinta todo ya ordenado despues de 1 segundo en vez de en cada iteración.

Comment: @ChavaSantos agregué un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

Comment: Probé lo que dices de incrementa el intervalo pero me sigue dibujando unicamente el arreglo ya ordenado, creo que mas bien mi problema tiene que ver con esta funcion: requestAnimationFrame(). Estoy leyendo al respecto. Igualmente agradezco tu tiempo y tu primer ejemplo si me sirvió.